# How to delete all php variables available (set then to null) using foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

In my page i have many php variables available `eg. $a, $b, $f, $t, $er, $de12` then i want to delete all those variables using foreach. How can i do that ?

i use this code but it´s not working. It's showing an error too

```
<?PHP
$ing_key ="1234567890";
$last = "love";
$phone = "088977";

$buff=($);
foreach($buff as $k=>$value){
   if($k!=='') $[$k]=null;
}
echo $ing_key;
echo "<br>";
echo $last;
echo "<br>";
echo $phone;
?>
```

Comment: What do you think you are doing with this $buff = ($) ?

Comment: That code is clearly invalid...we can't help.  Like Mike said...$buff=($) is nothing

Answer (score 1):

This code do what you need:

```
$vars = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
foreach($vars as $var) {
    unset(${"$var"}); # or may be reset them to empty string or set null# ${"$var"} = "";
}
```

Comment: how to set it to null available php

Comment: inside the loop, you put ${"$var"} = null; instead of unset(${"$var"});

Comment: i can add that to answer if you think it´s needed